# Excel automatically assumes a date+time format and when choosing text format it generates an unrelated number

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time, regional-settings

How can I format a cell in Excel to show time and date, with milliseconds, I have tried using :

```
(jjjj-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000)
```

Here's the raw CSV:

```
2021-02-11 17:32:43.177
2021-02-11 17:32:43.912
2021-02-11 17:32:44.637
2021-02-11 17:32:45.362
2021-02-11 17:32:46.086
2021-02-11 17:32:46.809
2021-02-11 17:32:47.536
2021-02-11 17:32:48.259
2021-02-11 17:32:48.985
2021-02-11 17:32:49.709
2021-02-11 17:32:50.443
2021-02-11 17:32:51.167
2021-02-11 17:32:51.890
```

In picture:

[image]

Here's what excel shows:

[image]

This is what we get when we select General:

[image]

This is with Text format:

[image]

And here are my regional settings:

[image]

Comment: Add some of your raw data into the question so I can copy it into excel

Comment: also, what are you doing in Row 6 for it to work ?

Comment: @PeterH I added some raw data for you. Not sure why row 6 works, don't see any logical explanation for that...

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. When I set up my computer to use `French(Switzerland)` settings, the format string becomes: `aaaa-mm-jj hh:mm:ss,000`.  Does that help.  *(Your lines that don't get changed are being interpreted as text strings)*.

Comment: The 'unrelated numbers' are the days and fractions of a day since `1-Jan-1900` which is how Excel stores date/time values